# Share internet connection from site to another over phone line

Tags: networking, internet, modem, dial-up

Preface:  I grew up in the Ethernet era and have never had to deal with a phone modem for internet.

I am having a long term internet outage at a site, but still have a phone connection.  Another site has internet and also phone.  Is it possible for me to share the internet connection like in the days of dial-up internet?  If so how?

Comment: How long term is "long term"? Frankly, using a dialup modem connection isn't going to be practical with most modern content due to the sheer increase in size and bandwidth requirements of modern OSes and programs.

Comment: Even a very good connection and 56K modems will yield just over 50K bandwidth. It could take days to download things like a Windows update.

Comment: Agreed that 56k would probably not be worth the effort

Comment: Also, phones may still be charged by the minute in many places.

Comment: Is it not possible to purchase a 3G dongle for the period?

Comment: I am probably going to go the cellular method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Hardware wise, you just need two modems. For software, you can probably still find free PPP server software somewhere. There are probably still Linux HOWTOs telling you how to set up a Linux box as a PPP server. PPP client software is still built into most OSes.

Beware that the fastest speed you can get with two analog modems is 33,600 bits per second (4 KiBytes per second). So-called 56k modems were really only 53k, and only in the download direction, and only when the ISP modem was connected to a digital phone line like an ISDN line. The best you can do with normal analog phone lines on both ends is 33,600 bits per second. And that's assuming perfect line conditions.

Do you have 3G/4G/LTE service at the site with no broadband? If so, you might do better with a mobile hotspot ( either a smartphone in hotspot mode, or dedicated hardware like a Mi-Fi).

Comment: It is a good point about the analogue phone lines. In the UK at least they are all digital unless otherwise specified in the contract.